# Google Sheets Query if blank

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language

I have the following query which works fine except if there is not a value in D that matches F2.  I get #N/A but not sure how to correct it so it shows "0".

```
=ABS(QUERY(Transactions,"SELECT SUM(E) WHERE D = '"&$F2&"' AND B > date '"&TEXT($C$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B <= date '"&TEXT($C$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' GROUP BY D LABEL SUM(E) '' ",0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=IFERROR(ABS(QUERY(Transactions,
 "SELECT SUM(E) 
  WHERE D = '"&$F2&"' 
    AND B >  date '"&TEXT($C$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    AND B <= date '"&TEXT($C$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  GROUP BY D 
  LABEL SUM(E) '' ", 0)), 0)
```

The function used is the **IFERROR**:

> Returns the first argument if it is not an error value, otherwise returns the second argument if present, or a blank if the second argument is absent.

You can check on the use and further explanation of it on the following link:

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en